# Reusing IDs in SVGs that are embedded in html: invalid html?

Tags: html, svg

Using the same IDs on the same html page is invalid: how does this transfer to SVGs? Different SVGs might reuse the same ids in subelements, and when including them in the html document they are part of the same DOM (?). So would this make the html invalid?

When styling SVGs one will often target layers/elements in the svgs using nested ids due to this, but not sure if this is fishy or not ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If the SVGs are inlined in the HTML then it matters.  It is technically an invalid document and you will likely get rendering errors.

This applies in particular to elements in the SVG that are refernced by other elements, eg, gradients, filters etc.  If the ids are not used by anything then the document will be fine.